# Dwm.exe memory leak when resizing simple WinForm application

Tags: windows, winforms, memory-leaks, datagridview, dwm

I created very simple Winform application in VS2010 (just a standard template File->New->Project->C# Windows Forms Application).

After several form resizes the system memory consumption can increase by 1Gb or more! And this memory is not returned to the system after application closing. Selecting Classic theme or killing dwm.exe helps to get memory back.

Here is the simple video I recorded to show the problem: http://youtu.be/ZJMCayflrHI

What can I do to get rid of this leak? Is it known issue?

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem on Windows 7 64bit

Comment: This is just yet another case of the common Windows memory myths.  The myths that task manager is a good memory profiler and that Windows will instantly stop using RAM.  Read Russonivich' Windows Internals to understand what's going on.

Comment: I just checked with "Process Explorer" and it also indicates that dwm.exe leaks. After several resizes dwm.exe memory consumption increased from 4 Mb to 200 Mb, then I continued to resize window and when dwm ate all system memory, the entire Windows completely freezed for about half a minute. After that dwm had restarted (maybe after crash), all memory was returned back to system and OS continued to work good.

Comment: Moreover, the problem is not reproducible on 64bit systems or with disabled Windows Aero. I think it looks more like a bug than a myth :)

Comment: Can you add a few more details: How much memory does the application use after start? How often did you resize? The video isn't publicly available :-(

Comment: This seems to be the case on Windows 10 with WPF applications as well. Still...

Comment: @AndreAndersen funny) This is one of my earliest questions on SO :) Keep it up Microsoft, will I see another comment in 2027?